# Criteria query on a property of a one-to-many property in GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a one-to-many relationship between the following example classes:

```
Class Home {
    static hasMany = [loans: Loan]

    int numStories
}

Class Loan {
    static belongsTo = [Bank]

    Home  home
    int   yearIssued 
}

Class Bank {
    SortedSet loans
    static  hasMany   = [loans: Loan]

    boolean active
}
```

I'm trying to write a named query that gets all active Bank objects that have Loans issued in 2007 on Homes of 2 stories.  In the Bank namedQueries I tried:

```
static namedQueries = { 
    myNamedQuery { yearIssued, numStories ->

        eq 'active', true
        loans {
            gt 'yearIssued', yearIssued

            home {
                eq 'numStories', numStories
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the "home { eq ... }" portion above, the query works fine, it just doesn't limit to 2 stories.  When executed as above, I get a groovy.lang.MissingMethodException error like:

```
   No signature of method: package.stuff.Home.call() is applicable for argument types
(package.stuff.Bank$__clinit__closure3_closure10_closure20_closure21) 
values: [package.stuff.Bank$__clinit__closure3_closure10_closure20_closure21@746231ed];

    Possible solutions: wait(), last(), save(), any(), getAll(), wait(long)"
```

How would I limit the Banks returned to those that have loans on homes with 2 stories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after many attempts I was never able to get it working using the direct association dsl with more than one level of association.  I was able to get it to work using aliases:

```
 static namedQueries = { 
   myNamedQuery { yearIssued, numStories ->
     eq 'active', true
     createAlias 'loans','l'
     createAlias 'l.home','h'
     gt('l.yearIssued', yearIssued)
     eq('h.numStories',numStories)
  }
}
```

An then call it using

```
def bankInstanceList = Bank.myNamedQuery(2007,2).list()
```

I'm not sure at the moment why this is - could be a bug or just designed behavior I don't understand.

Hopefully this at least gets you going...

Comment: Thanks!  I was running all this in a unit test, and apparently in my test setup, createAlias fails.  I tested your solution in a "real" setup and it indeed works.  The fun part is that the original way of using the direct association works in the "real" environment too without error.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924669/kelly),

To finally get you the clarification after so long time,
I assume we are using restrictions like "gt, eq" on non primary-key column such as loans -> yearIssued, home -> numStories.

Only in such condition, to navigate to association paths like loans, home; we need to create alias.

Where do we not need alias:

1. No restrictions to be applied
2. Restrictions applied only on associated entity primary-key column.

Hopefully, this clarifies the thing and may help someone.